# replace geometry within geodataframe with the union of geometries

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I am trying to replace existing geometry of polygon by merging with neighboring polygon.

new_gdf -> geodataframe containing polygons

r       -> rings of type polygon to be merged with polygons

union   -> could be polygon or multipolygon

```
new_gdf = gdf.copy(deep=True)

for r in list(rings):
    for i in range(0, len(new_gdf)):
        if new_gdf.iloc[i][10].intersects(r):
            new_gdf.at[i, 'geom'] = unary_union([new_gdf.iloc[i][10], r])
            break
```

This is giving me error `Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable` but couldn't find out what could be the reason and how to solve that.

Comment: Is the error happening in line 6 in your code segment? Does the type returned by `unary_union()` match the column type?